# Mustache {{}} binding for vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a list array and I numbered each element object by using row index like this.

```
{{tableData[props.index-1] = props.index }}
```

This worked very well.

I thought it would be left one `(tableData[props.index-1])` but fortunately my guess was wrong. It seems the value inside mustache is right side one`(props.index)`.

I’d liked to know why, and how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Inside `{{ }}` in a Vue template you are evaluating a JavaScript expression. The result of the expression `a = b` is `b`.

There is nothing Vue-specific about this behaviour:

```js
let a;
console.log(a = 1); // output: 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! :-)